# Changing lifecycle in VueJS

Tags: vue.js, lifecycle

I am working on a project with VueJS. I found a little bit weird behavior about the lifecycle.

I have a parent component, named Profile, and also a child component, named Post. The codes are attached below.

Parent component:

```js
import { ModalUserEdition, Post } from "../../components";
import { mapGetters, mapMutations, mapActions } from "vuex";
import {
  GET_PROFILE_INFO,
  GET_USER,
  EDIT_USER
} from "../../store/types/actions.type";

export default {
  // ellipsis
  
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters([
      "profile",
      "profileUserId",
      "profileUserNickname",
      "profileUserPosts",  // the elements of the list will be passed to Post component.
      "currentUserId"
    ])
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions([GET_PROFILE_INFO]),
    showUserEditionModal() {
      this.isShowUserEditionModal = !this.isShowUserEditionModal;
    }
  },
  created() {
    console.log('instantiated');
    console.log('profile created');
    this.getProfileInfo(this.$route.query.id);  // Vuex action
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log('profile mounted');
  }
};
```

```html
<template>
    <!-- ellipsis -->

    <div class="posts">
      <post v-for="(post, index) in profileUserPosts" :key="index" :post="post"></post>
      <div class="welcome-message" v-if="profileUserPosts.length === 0">
        <!-- Some Message -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Child component:

```js
import { mapGetters, mapActions } from "vuex";

export default {
  props: {
    post: {
      type: Object
    }
  },
  created() {
    console.log('post created');
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log('post mounted');
  }
};
```

Console returns in two ways as follows:
[Console result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LV4X.png)

The workflow:
parent created -> child created -> child mounted -> parent mounted  <- This is what I expect

or

parent created -> parent mounted -> child created -> child mounted

So the parent and child lifecycle hook changes somehow, even though the code doesn't change.

Could you explain this to me?

Answer (score 0):

why do you want to use a life cycle like that? As far as I know, the life cycle cannot be changed, it's because you call the child component in the parent component I think that can't be implemented.

Comment: I needed to compute a derived state based on store state in the parent component to pass the data to the child component, however, I could not pass the data correctly due to the changing lifecycle, which is what I guess though. That's why I wanted to check if the lifecycle changes. I agree with you on the point that the lifecycle doesn't change.